# Mobile Publisher App Error: You do not have API access enabled

Tags: mobile-publisher

**BACKGROUND**

We have a Mobile App using [Mobile Publisher](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.s1_branded_apps.htm&type=5)

When you install the `Managed Package` for each app (iOS and Android), it adds two `Connected Apps` which the native apps use to authenticate with Salesforce.

When a user logs in they are getting a little warning/error message:

> You do not have API access enabled, which may cause some functionality issues. Ask your admin for assistance

There is a help article which I believe covers this:

- [Create a Permission Set and Grant API Enabled Access (Optional)](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.branded_apps_commun_api_permset.htm&type=5)

As per the article, I've created the permission set.

But I've assigned it to the `Connected Apps` rather than the users because new users are being added constantly.

But it's not working.

**QUESTIONS**

1. Should applying it to the `Connected App` work as I believe?
2. Is the solution to just add the permission to the Customer Community Profile?

Answer (score 0):

- set `Api Enabled` system permission to `true` for the profile assigned to the community user.
- Add the connected app to the same profile.

this should work. Doing the same settings for a permission set (instead of a profile) assigned to the community user should also work